# Number of entries in the file

Tags: 14.04

I have json-file with the entries in the dictionary format (actually strings). What is the terminal order in linux, which get me the full number of entries back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334348/how-to-count-items-in-json-object-using-command-line

Comment: @rishiag dupes only count when on AU itself ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Ohk. Will keep in mind for future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also find some specific function in Linux terminal

```
wc file.json
```

This function get back the number of lines, of words and of characters in some file.

Answer (score 1):

JSON can have all sorts of formatting that make it hard to read without properly parsing it. I would farm this out to something like Python. You can still keep it within Bash and using pipes, but that's optional:

```
$ echo '[1, 2, 3]' | python -c 'import json,sys; print len(json.load(sys.stdin))'
3
```

This is obviously a very simple example but it's a good starter for doing complex lookups too.